# Power BI : How to remove all excel number formatting while importing a file in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have an excel file (*.xlsb) where big numbers are shown in reduced form/custom format for easy understanding using custom number formatting (#,##0,;[Red]-#,##0,).

Eg.1: number 44526271 is shown as 44,526.

Eg.2: number -10273666.12 is shown as -10,274.

In short, when you open the excel, the numbers are shown in reduced form but when you click the cell you will be able to see full number in the formula bar.

Now when I am trying to import this excel in PowerBI, it is only importing the number displayed in the cell and not the original/full number (hint: above 44 million is imported as 44526, -10 million is imported as -10274 and likewise).

I have no access to modify the excel or to remove the custom formatting, is there a way to import the actual numbers by removing the formatting?

Comment: Power BI uses a different connector for xlsb files (than for xlsx and xlsm files) which seems to input the formatted value and not the actual value stored in the cell.  Without access to the original file, what you want may not be possible.  But I will follow this thread with interest as hopefully, I am wrong. If you can import the xlsb file; maybe you could download it and convert it to an xlsm file?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks for your inputs. We have an internal application which writes data to this xlsb file stored on a network drive. This writing to .xlsb task happens daily and then we have a scheduled refresh on the server to refresh data from this file. This is the reason I cannot do anything to modify the file at source. Because the file is replaced on a daily basis.